# Change KDE apps color in Unity (systemsetting incomplete)

Tags: unity, themes, kde, colors

I can't modify KDE apps colors, there isn't a "colors" section/module in systemsettings neither in kcmshell4 nor in kcmshell5. Is there a solution to this, I want to stay in Unity anyway, and avoid installing entire plasma 5.

**Update**

[image: screenshot of the problem]

If possible I would like to change the theme, make it the most flat possible... But this is another setting I don't have access.

**Update 2**

After installing `plasma-desktop-data`, settings showed up, but they have no effect on KDE apps.

[image]!

As we can see, the result is in no way what breeze really look like.  The app I used as an example is `KSysGuard`.

Comment: A screenshot would be fine

Comment: @Anwar Sorry for the lack, added an screenshot and thanks for the attention.

Comment: An answer is given. You can check and try the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color settings in Kde System Settings is provided by `plasma-desktop-data` package. You need to install that one to have the settings shown there.

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop-data
```

This package provides color settings as well as many others such as *Font*, *Icons*, *Workspace*, *Desktop Behavior*, *Shortcuts* etc. It seems there is no minimal package to just provide the color settings changeability.

Comment: Unfortunately any change I do to colors or any other setting, have no effect, even after a reboot.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti Can you see the color settings now?

Comment: Yes, I can see practically all settings but unfortunately they have no effect.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti hmm... That's a problem appeared after your original problem of not seeing the settings has solved.  You can try asking another question for that problem. Which program's settings you were trying to change?

Comment: I would be happy if I could at last change the theme... I will considere it answered for now, will search a little more myself and If I get success I will add here...

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti let me then check again. can you post a screenshot of the system settings after you tried the solution?

Comment: Sure, will add a second update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45844/discussion-between-romulopbenedetti-and-anwar).